# Apache kafka member connector-consumer-group connect-kafka has failed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I got below issue from kafka-server log after that warning the other exception followed that warning. İs there any way to figure it out. My kafka version:2.6.0

First warning;

```
Kafka's member connector-consumer-group-1asdfsdf in group connect-kafka-a has failed. Group connect-kafka-a is now empty  (__consumer_offsets-14) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator).
```

Following Exception;

```
    [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Error sending fetch request 
    (sessionId=452321706, epoch=788566371) to node 3: 
    (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
    java.io.IOException: Connection to 3 was disconnected before the response was read
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:100)
    at 
    kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.scala:108)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetchFromLeader(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:207)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:300)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:135)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.maybeFetch(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:134)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:117)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
```